# search query count two fields and result into a 1 row group by

Tags: mysql, select

I have a table in which i want to result this in one row group by the orig call and term call. I will count how many times it has incoming and outgoing..here's the tables

**call TABLE**

```
|ID | originating call |   terminating call |  call type    
| 1 | 123              |       123          |  incoming
| 2 | 123              |       123          |  outgoing
| 3 | 123              |       321          |  incoming
| 4 | 123              |       321          |  incoming
```

the result should be

```
 originating call |   terminating call |  incoming  | outgoing
      123         |       123          |     1      |    1
      123         |       321          |     2      |    0
```

I have tried the count(*) as incoming and count(*) as outgoing but I don't know what should I do next. Should I group it by originating call and terminating call?

Comment: Is this SQL Server or MySQL?  Which database are you really using?

Comment: What are you using: `MySQL` or `SQL Server`?  Could there be `call type` other that the two values shown?

Comment: @PM77-1   sorry for the tags, i used mysql ..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is called conditional aggregation.  You can do the basic query using a `case` statement:

```
select originating, terminating,
       sum(case when calltype = 'incoming' then 1 else 0 end) as incoming,
       sum(case when calltype = 'outgoing' then 1 else 0 end) as outgoing,
from calltable ct
group by originating, terminating;
```

This works in all databases.  To get the `id` column differs among databases.  In SQL Server, you would do:

```
select row_number() over (order by (select NULL)) as id,
       originating, terminating,
       sum(case when calltype = 'incoming' then 1 else 0 end) as incoming,
       sum(case when calltype = 'outgoing' then 1 else 0 end) as outgoing,
from calltable ct
group by originating, terminating;
```

In MySQL, you would get the `id` as:

```
select @id := @id + 1 as id,
       originating, terminating,
       sum(calltype = 'incoming') as incoming,
       sum(calltype = 'outgoing') as outgoing,
from calltable ct cross join
     (select @id := 0) const
group by originating, terminating;
```

Although `case` works fine in MySQL, this version uses a short-hand that is convenient in this situation.

Comment: shouldn't it be count instead of sum?

Comment: i think i get it why you use the SUM() because of the return if 1 or 0 ? am i right?

Comment: @Vincent - You got it.

Answer (score 0):

Use below Query :

```
select originating, terminating,
       sum(case when calltype ='incoming' then 1 else 0 end) as incoming,
       sum(case when calltype ='outgoing' then 1 else 0 end) as outgoing,
from Table_Name
```

group by originating, terminating;